# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

i need to set 'ConnectionString' for access asp website and ms db. but show below error. anyone can help?? thanks

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long

```
Application("ConnectionString") = "Provider=xxxx ;Password=xxx;User ID=xxx;Initial Catalog=xx;Data Source=xxxx"
```

Comment: I think that error is misleading. That error looks to be a x32 bit vs x64 bit error. Are you running the site as x64, but perhaps have x32 Access (jet/ace) installed? You have to match up the bit size of the Access driver you install + use on your site.

Comment: thanks Albert, you mean install ODBC?thanks

Comment: Actaully, I mean that you have to install the Access data engine - and the x64 bit one if you web site is running as x64 bits (and it will/is in most cases). So you have to install the ACE data engine (that's the data engine used for Access). You don't need to have or install Access, nor even the Access runtime, but you do have to install at "least" the data engine. This one: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920  --- make sure you download + pick the x64 bit one. Also note that during developing VS - the test connection will ALWAYS fail for x64 - but debug/run works